# How big does a lake have to be to have its own Sea Breeze?

Tags: atmosphere, wind, geography, convection, mesoscale-meteorology

How big does a body of water need to have a sea breeze? Is there a chart on sea breezes wind speed that include lakes?

Could a circular lake create enough sea breeze to create a wind vortex in the center of the lake?
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108896/could-a-city-be-built-out-of-balloons

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great question.  Lake Breezes are quite common... with the Great Lakes and Lake Okeechobee both commonly impactful.  But often see lake breezes even on much small lakes such as Lake Apopka in Florida, and even boundaries come off rivers occasionally.  Basically any temperature gradient can cause some sort of circulation, it's just whether it's its strong enough to impact clouds and such to be noted.  Remind me in a couple months when it's warmer (and thus can be regularly seen in FL), and will try to delete this and write up an answer using some imagery/models showing them :)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest - looking forward to your mesoscale model output. But looking at Lake Apopka - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Apopka it is no small lake at least in my view of the world.

Comment: @gansub, true, true, I get spoiled by the land of large lakes.  It's the 5th largest in Florida, and only 6% the size of Lake Okeechobee... so I still call it "much smaller" :-p

Comment: The temperature of the lake will also be important and that will depend on thermal mass, depth, and circulation within the lake. The characteristics and heating of the land also make a difference. To make things even more complicated the effects will be superimposed on the regional weather, which could either enhance or counteract the effect.

Comment: (I didn't forget btw!  And did save a few pertinent images this summer.  Not sure I'll be able to perfectly answer all your interests, but hoping I can at least put something together eventually... just been busy/distracted/dealing with things like computer issues recently :-) )

Comment: Also note... sinking motion, like shown at the center of your diagram, may look like a whirlpool shape or such to you, but it's really the structure of anticyclones... higher pressure, which lead to somewhat lighter winds generally... probably not favorable for what you're seeking!  All vertical motion in the atmosphere is actually fairly similar in shape... rising motion must match up with air moving towards the center (at the bottom) and sinking motion must match up with air moving away from the center... or else the area will lose/gain air significantly and the pressure would change a ton.

Comment: But perhaps wait until I can piece together the answer from those images I saved, as there were good model and satellite imagery showing more of the structure of such phenomena.  And I can also address the rotation potential a bit if that is part of your interest in the "vortex" part of the question.  Sorry to keep you waiting so long, so many questions I keep faltering to give answers to :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lake breezes(similar to sea breezes) are fundamentally a feature of mesoscale meteorology and the peer reviewed reference [Small Lake Daytime Breezes:
Some Observational and
Conceptual Evaluations](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0477%281997%29078%3C1135%3ASLDBSO%3E2.0.CO%3B2) details both the observational studies of lake breezes and the conceptual understanding behind the formation of the lake breeze.

Since OP's question is

> How big does a body of water need to have a sea breeze?

The answer according to this book [Climate in a small area](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0860081443) which is one of the references in the first reference is that lake breezes have been observed in lakes with a width of about 4 kms([Lake Suwa, Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Suwa) ) and a width of 10 kms ([Lake Constance, Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Constance)). The lake breeze reached a speed of 2 m $s^{-1}$ in the case of Lake Suwa and slightly greater speed in the case of Lake Constance. But because both of these lakes are orographic lakes the presence of thermally induced upslope flows (diurnal heating and consequent upslope flows during the day)  can interfere with the formation of lake breeze.

Further observational studies carried much later for the following lakes  [Lake El Dorado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Dorado_Lake) , [Lake Okeechobee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Okeechobee), [Lake Winnipeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Winnipeg) and [Lake Eufaula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eufaula_Lake) have reported lake breeze speed values in the range of 2-4 m $s^{-1}$. One must remember that these lakes are much larger in size but in essence the numbers capture the range of the lake breeze values. These observations had been obtained as a result of measurements carried out over a period of few months and over different weather conditions.

The upper range for the lake breeze is around 6 m $s^{-1}$ and any lake having a width of less than 2 km is likely to have an undetectable lake breeze.

So the physics behind the lake breeze formation in essence is similar to the physics behind the sea breeze formation. A pressure gradient(density gradient) is created between the land and the lake and this gradient is primarily established in the lower troposphere. Greater the inland sensible heat flux greater the value of the pressure gradient.

The following URL shows satellite images of different stages of formation of a lake breeze during the day - [Lake Breeze Satellite Imagery](https://www.weather.gov/bgm/WeatherInActionLakeShadowBreeze)

In regards to the second question I believe [steam devils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_devil) are mesoscale vortices that have been observed to form over lakes. These vortices are no more than 50-200 meters wide and can develop in the absence of any major synoptic scale forcing. But the surface area of the lakes have to be in the range of [Great Lakes of North America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Lakes)  in order for the strong surface heat fluxes to play a role in mesoscale vortex development. The following peer reviewed reference provides observational and modeling studies of steam devils- [Mesoscale spiral vortex embedded within a lake](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0493%281988%29116%3C1374%3AMSVEWA%3E2.0.CO%3B2)

Comment: Great answer. Steam Devils are interesting. Does the lake breeze vortex when the wind meets in the middle over a smaller lake?  Can it keep an idle vessel in the middle of the lake or a blimp over the center of the lake? The vortex maybe very wide and 5+mph and not visible.

Comment: @Muze - I am not sure whether I understood your question. But IMHO steam devils are simply not possible in smaller lakes. For smaller lakes with favorable synoptic scale forcing you can have external vortices move in over the lake.

Comment: yes. they would not get steam Devils it would be something completely different.  I don't know if there is a name for it yet. I'm just saying smaller lakes that have a lake breeze then what happens when that llake breeze meets in the middle?

Comment: @Muze - What do you mean when you write - lake breeze meets in the middle ? A lake breeze moves from water to land. Smaller lakes simply do not have the capacity to produce a vortex. Synoptic scale systems can create a lot of disturbance when it moves into the middle of the lake. But that uses energy from "outside" the lake.

Comment: @Muze are you referring to a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterspout ? They can form over lakes as well but more over the tropics than mid latitudes

Comment: They can move both ways depending on if it is night or day. During the day the air would meet at a higher altitude. At night the breeze would meet just above the water.

Comment: I don't think it has been observed but may exist. the vortex would not be much faster then the breeze.

Comment: @Muze at night it is called land breeze. Lake breeze can move only direction from water to land.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I want to think there would be more chances of a lake breeze vortex occurring at night.